# How to scan user input and print a string if a key word matches?

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I'm basically trying to make a very simple chatter bot for my school work, I've been trying to figure out how to display a certain text of string when a key word is entered by the user.

For example they program will ask "Please choose from on of these subjects (maths, english, science)", and the user will type something like "I would like to choose science" and then the program will scan the users input looking for the keywords 'english, maths and science' and if it finds one of them it will display a string message, if it doesn't find any it will display a string message saying error.

So far I've made one if statement but it only works if the user input exactly as I made the if statement, while I need it to scan the user input and if a key word is used anywhere it will display the sentence.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ChatterBot {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String input = "";
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What subject do you want to choose mate (maths, english, science) ");

        if (input.equals("maths")) {
            input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Maths is fun and used a lot in subjects");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You may use the `contains` method instead of `equals`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equals means that the input has to be identical to "maths". If you just want to check if the input contains the word "maths", use:

```
if (input.contains("maths")) {
    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Maths is fun and used a lot in subjects");
}
```